# Не работает repeat в спрайте (Godot 4, Mono)

Tags: godot

У меня есть тайл со спрайтами для игры. Мне нужно создать фон. Я создал спрайт, задал границы в *Region* и задал свойство *Texture | Repeat* в *Enabled*. При растягивании спрайта в редакторе, также растягивается и текстура, а мне нужно, чтобы она повторялась.
[image: Скриншот с движка]

Помогите пожалуйста!
*П.с: при использовании окна Импорт, флаг **Repeat — отсутствует**.*